# convert input name variable by trim function to search in database

Tags: laravel

hello every one i want to do some search it's work but when i put in form for example "testtest" and in databse be like "test test" no result displayin , so i think that a trim() function could help me but i don't know how to use it

this is the controller

```
public function search(Request $request){

        $search=trim($request->get('search'));

         $user=User::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')
          ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
          ->orWhere('telephone', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
          ->orWhere('adresse', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
          if(count($user)>0){
            return view('users.gestionUser',array('user' => $user));

          }else{
            Session::flash('message',' '.$search.' n\'a pas été trouvé');

            return view('users.gestionUser',array('user' => $user));
          }

        }
```

Comment: The trim function will not work here. What do you want to try? remove spaces from the strings in the database?

Comment: @Jerodev I just want the names to be exact and find them in the database even if they do not have the same order of spaces , for exemple 'testtest' to be like 'test  test' and get the result , i don't want the spaces to make differences between those two variables in search form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `str_replace` [doc](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)

You would use it as such:

```
$search=str_replace(' ', '', trim($request->get('search'));
```

Assuming you are trying to search for `testtest` and not `test test`.

If you are trying to search for `test test` it will fail because of the `%` wildcard you are using in the database.

Comment: iw ant to when i search for 'test test' get 'testest'  and vice versa

Comment: thank you bro it help ,but why when i search for 'test 2' nothing result display even it exist already in database

Comment: @fouadmad can you provide us with an example? There must be some kind of mistype maybe because I don't see the problem. You said in the last comment you need to get `test test` and `testtest` but you didn't provide with an example of what is in your database